# Bash: renaming file extension, getting errors

Tags: bash, rename

```
root@myhost# ./removedott.sh
Mon Nov 23 10:07:04 EST 2015 - Renaming tester.xml.P.T extension to xml
mv: `tester.xml.P.T' and `tester.xml' are the same file
```

removedott.sh:

```
if [[ $(find . -type f -name "*.T"  | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
        then
              for f in *.T
                        do
                                echo "`date` - Renaming $f extension to xml"
                                y=${f%%.*}
                                mv -v -- "$f" "${y}.xml"
                                done
fi
```

I dont know why that error is coming up, I realize the file are the same.. thats the whole purpose.. I just want to rename it.

Comment: Do you have a `tester.xml` file in the directory already? (Also that `find` test is likely better replaced by just enabling `nullglob` and/or testing for `*.T` as the value of `$f` in the loop.)

Comment: in the directory I do:
touch tester.abc.T
then run the script, on the first pass it removes the .abc.T and the renames it to tester.xml.

If I then mv tester.xml to tester.abc.T and run the script again, thats when I get the error

Comment: If it already exists with the name you want and you know it, why do you want to rename it?  I smell an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @EtanReisner why would it not just overwrite if it was already there ?

Comment: Hm, true, I wouldn't expect `mv` to output that. Is that the actual script? You aren't using `ln` or `cp -l` or anything like that?

Comment: y=${f%%.*}
 cp $f $y.xml
 rm $f

I tried this and CP gave me the same error two (works first time, but not the 2nd)

Mon Nov 23 10:31:34 EST 2015 - Renaming tester.xml.P.T extension to xml
cp: `tester.xml.P.T' and `tester.xml' are the same file

Comment: Is it possible that `tester.xml` and `tester.xml.P.T` are already two hard links to the same file? Run `ls -li` and check the first column for each file. If it's the same number, they are already the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these solutions, even mine work just fine.  This ended up being a process on the host that was affecting the file during the rename.  Linux couldn't find the file during that time.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to why your `mv` is not working, but just another version of the script that does the same thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Renames ".T" extensions to ".xml" extensions for files in the current
# directory and subdirectories
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.T"); do
    echo "$(date) - Renaming $file extension to .xml"
    mv -v $file $(echo $file | sed 's/\.T$/\.xml/g')
done
```

This works for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Not a safe solution (doesn't handle files with whitespace or shell glob characters correctly). See [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for details.